# Android One Tap SignIn, nonce is missing from the generated ID Token

Tags: android, google-signin, google-identity, google-one-tap

According to the documentation [setNonce](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/identity/BeginSignInRequest.GoogleIdTokenRequestOptions.Builder#setNonce(java.lang.String))

I expect the nonce will be included as a claim from the IDToken, however, after setting the nonce with the following code:

```
      oneTapClient = Identity.getSignInClient(getContext());
        BeginSignInRequest signInRequest = BeginSignInRequest.builder()
                .setGoogleIdTokenRequestOptions(BeginSignInRequest.GoogleIdTokenRequestOptions.builder()
                        .setSupported(true)
                        .setServerClientId(clientId)
                        .setNonce("5qb6kvo0q8drrzs50dkv5uzci1ft7p1")
                        .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
                        .build())
                .build();
```

and get the id token from:

```
SignInCredential credential = null;
            try {
                credential = oneTapClient.getSignInCredentialFromIntent(data);
                String idToken = credential.getGoogleIdToken();
               
            } catch (ApiException e) {
               ...
            }
```

Decode the returned idToken, the nonce is missing.

Is it a defect? or did I miss something?

Also, in the documentation [Verify the integrity of the ID token](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/idtoken-auth#verify-the-integrity-of-the-id-token), it does not mention the nonce validation defined under  [ID Token Validation](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDTokenValidation)

Comment: *Is it a defect? or did I miss something?* - I noticed the same, also tokens returned from the new Google Sign-In API are missing the `nonce`. I opened an issue in Google's Issue Tracker referencing your question [#193457108](https://issuetracker.google.com/193457108).

Comment: We are looking into this and will update the thread shortly.

Comment: Let me describe a use case. A user comes to my site as a guest. They are tracked with a session ID. They read all the quantum physics articles. Peter, Paul, and Mary google sign-in to my site. Are one of them the guest user? I'll never know because I don't have a nonce to correlate session IDs with their google identity. Their pre-sign-in behavior is lost.

Comment: This issue should be fixed now, please try again.

Comment: Verified, the nonce issue is resolved, however, there is another issue related to the Google Identity Services https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69215814/google-identity-services-returns-16-cannot-find-a-matching-credential-when-goog