# Google Identity Services returns 16: Cannot find a matching credential when Google Account has not been added

Tags: android, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

I would like to migrate the existing Google Sign-In API [Google Sign-In API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in) to [Google Identity Service](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in-identity), however, Google Identity Service returns "16: Cannot find a matching credential" when Google Account has not been added.

Here is the step to reproduce:

1. Make sure there is no Google Account setup, Settings -> Account:
   [image]
2. Request Google SignIn with the following code:

```java
SignInClient client = Identity.getSignInClient(getContext());

       BeginSignInRequest.GoogleIdTokenRequestOptions.Builder builder = BeginSignInRequest.GoogleIdTokenRequestOptions.builder()
               .setSupported(true)
               // Your server's client ID, not your Android client ID.
               .setServerClientId(clientId)
               .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false);


       BeginSignInRequest signInRequest = BeginSignInRequest.builder()
               .setGoogleIdTokenRequestOptions(builder.build())
               .build();

       client.beginSignIn(signInRequest)
               .addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), result -> {
                   try {
                       startIntentSenderForResult(
                               result.getPendingIntent().getIntentSender(), RC_SIGN_IN,
                               null, 0, 0, 0, null);
                   } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                       //handle error
                   }
               })
               .addOnFailureListener(getActivity(), e -> {
                   // No saved credentials found. Launch the One Tap sign-up flow, or
                   // do nothing and continue presenting the signed-out UI.
               });
```

3. Got 16: Cannot find a matching credential

By using the old interface [Google Sign-In API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in), it works as expected, it created the Google Account and sign in the user. Also, the [Google Identity Service](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in-identity) works when there is a Google Account in the Account Manager.

Comment: you got any solution?

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: Still no solution?